# Smart Form is poping datepicker only not time picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker

I am using Smart Form plugin for date and time picker. Everything is been set up and working but I can see only calender poping up on text field whereas demo has time picker attached to it.
My html read like this:

```
<div class="smart-wrap">
<div class="smart-forms smart-container wrap-2">

    <div class="form-header header-primary">
        <h4><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> Date Time Picker </h4>
    </div><!-- end .form-header section -->

    <form method="post" action="/" id="smart-form">
        <div class="form-body">
            <div class="spacer-b30">
                <div class="tagline"><span> Inline date-time picker </span></div><!-- .tagline -->
            </div>

            <div class="section cal-widget">
                <div class="spacer-b10">
                    <input type="text" name="dtpfield" id="dtpfield" class="gui-input" />
                </div>
                <span id="dtpicker" ></span>
            </div><!-- end section --> 


            <div class="form-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="button btn-primary"> Submit Form </button>
                <button type="reset" class="button"> Cancel </button>
            </div><!-- end .form-footer section -->
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!-- end .smart-wrap section -->
```

My js read like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#dtpicker').datetimepicker({
         altField: "#dtpfield",
         altFieldTimeOnly: false,                   
         prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
         nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try by adding **timeFormat** in your code,like this,

```
$(function() {
    $('#dtpicker').datetimepicker({
         controlType: 'select',
    oneLine: true,
    timeFormat: 'hh:mm tt',                 
         prevText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
         nextText: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
    });
});
```